# email problems with directing to local ip

Tags: email, email-server

I am trying to direct emails to a local ip address and using another ip for website. The local guy told me to set it up like this
but it is not working . It is still going to the local webmail on my cPanel

Zone File Records

```
<Name   TTL Class   Type    Record  Action>
<odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40>
<localhost.odomnursery.com. 14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1>
<www.odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  CNAME   odomnursery.com>
<ftp.odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  CNAME   odomnursery.com>
<odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all">
cpanel.odomnursery.com. 14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40>
<whm.odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40>
<webmail.odomnursery.com.   14400   IN  A   207.144.155.51>
```

Comment: Whatever you tried to cut and paste didn't work well.  Maybe try again and use the Blockquote formatting button.

Comment: I can't see any `MX` record in the posted DNS records.

Comment: @Khaled Which isn't necessary as long as you have A records.

Comment: But that is the question - to separate web and email servers.

Comment: odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40
localhost.odomnursery.com.  14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
www.odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  CNAME   odomnursery.com
ftp.odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  CNAME   odomnursery.com
odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  TXT "v=spf1 a mx nclude:websitewelcome.com ~all"
cpanel.odomnursery.com. 14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40
whm.odomnursery.com.        14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40
webmail.odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  A   207.144.155.51
webdisk.odomnursery.com.    14400   IN  A   174.132.29.40
mail.odomnursery.com.       14400   IN  A   207.144.155.51

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following record

```
odomnursery.com 14400 IN MX 10 webmail.odomnursery.com
```

(Assuming your mail is like user@odomnursery.com, and the host that runs SMTP is webmail.odomnursery.com)

Comment: Sales@odomnursery.com

Comment: the mail was setup on 207.144.155.51   and the odomnursery.com is 174.132.29.40

Comment: Mark: replace mail.odomnursery.com with whatever hostname that have A record of 207.144.155.51 (like webmail.odomnursery.com)